# RStudio, set relative R path

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I'm using RStudio, and I have R in a folder inside the RStudio folder, I want to move this folder to other places to work, but I don't want to install it in every place.

(When we install Rstudio, the dir is "RStudio/bin" where the files are)

When using R in a different folder, I don't need to worry about the library path, R can handle from it self to where it is, and will set the path to where I move the R folder.

The part I can't found, is how can I tell to Rstudio to use a relative path to where the R folder is, like "./R", I know I can set the path in the options, but I'm looking for this.

The env vars of Rstudio help on R libs, but not R it self, maybe there is one, but I wasn't able to find it.

This is for windows.

I'll explain how the folders are structured:

```
Rstudio/ (Here all the files of RStudio)
RStudio/R (Here all the R files, bin and libs)
```

I want, when I open the file `RStudio/rstudio.exe`, to use the R version in RStudio/R, as a relative path "./R" where is the bins and libs.

So if I move the RStudio folder, will keep using the same R folder in the RStudio folder.

Thx.

Comment: The `here` package might help here. https://here.r-lib.org/

Comment: The ```here``` package, how would help me? can change the top lvl directories, but I can't see how to use it to load a particular path of R in RStudio, even, to use a package R must be loaded first...., sorry, I can't found how to use it to automatically specify the R path and bin. The question is not about a project, is about RStudio and the default R.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can rephrase or explain more, or give a specific example. Is this about running different versions of R on the same computer? At first I thought this was about reusing code for different projects, hence the reference to `here` (and you might look at this article: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/), but maybe you're asking something different.

Comment: Hope now is better explained, this is a RStudio question and relative path to set R.